# Planar clipping/merge with Mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror, snapping

I am looking at work-flows for building roofs.  Below was promising until I hit a snag...

[image: Image of two planes as (1) below]

#### Setup

1. Rotated Plane + Mirror modifier.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (Transform Orientation) > Normal
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > Create Orientation for sloped plane
4. <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> ...
5. When the two planes meet, they 'climb' up the global Z-axis, which I don't want (below)

[image: Image of displaced planes as (4) above]

#### Question

How do I constrain the merged verts to the selected Orientation (i.e. staying in line with the roof?

Comment: Why not using `Clipping` option of Mirror modifier ? It won't anwer your question, it should prevent that situation.